# When deployed on lambda, AWS Textract doesn't return 'LINE' or 'WORD' blocks, only 'PAGE' blocks

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ocr

My function works well when it runs locally and invokes Textract OCR, here is the output:

```
{'DocumentMetadata': {
'Pages': 1}, 
'JobStatus': 'SUCCEEDED', 
'Blocks': [
{'BlockType': 'PAGE', 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 1.0, 'Height': 1.0, 'Left': 0.0, 'Top': 0.0}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 1.956095047717099e-06, 'Y': 0.0}, {'X': 1.0, 'Y': 1.9269275526312413e-06}, {'X': 1.0, 'Y': 1.0}, {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 1.0}]}, 'Id': 'e3517e8d-3eb1-4c7a-8ffe-f4f4f40bd923', 'Relationships': [{'Type': 'CHILD', 'Ids': ['3261bf02-d63c-4016-a5b2-a437308de18d']}], 'Page': 1}, 
{'BlockType': 'LINE', 'Confidence': 99.86868286132812, 'Text': 'John Doe Is', 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.14190037548542023, 'Height': 0.013485041446983814, 'Left': 0.09458228200674057, 'Top': 0.06803429871797562}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 0.0945969745516777, 'Y': 0.06803429871797562}, {'X': 0.2364826500415802, 'Y': 0.06828282028436661}, {'X': 0.2364688366651535, 'Y': 0.08151934295892715}, {'X': 0.09458228200674057, 'Y': 0.08127062022686005}]}, 'Id': '3261bf02-d63c-4016-a5b2-a437308de18d', 'Relationships': [{'Type': 'CHILD', 'Ids': ['d6c105b6-2e5b-425c-bc2d-fda9c4ed1815', '223fbbe4-9a0c-4a26-8947-04bb7e535139', '1bc8b80b-4e35-4815-9843-ac901852e720']}], 'Page': 1}, 
{'BlockType': 'WORD', 'Confidence': 99.84158325195312, 'Text': 'John', 'TextType': 'PRINTED', 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.05469386279582977, 'Height': 0.013332170434296131, 'Left': 0.09458228200674057, 'Top': 0.06803429871797562}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 0.0945969745516777, 'Y': 0.06803429871797562}, {'X': 0.14927615225315094, 'Y': 0.06813007593154907}, {'X': 0.14926178753376007, 'Y': 0.08136647194623947}, {'X': 0.09458228200674057, 'Y': 0.08127062022686005}]}, 'Id': 'd6c105b6-2e5b-425c-bc2d-fda9c4ed1815', 'Page': 1}, 
{'BlockType': 'WORD', 'Confidence': 99.9034652709961, 'Text': 'Doe', 'TextType': 'PRINTED', 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.02554963529109955, 'Height': 0.01002489123493433, 'Left': 0.15451456606388092, 'Top': 0.0688563659787178}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 0.15452536940574646, 'Y': 0.0688563659787178}, {'X': 0.18006420135498047, 'Y': 0.06890109926462173}, {'X': 0.18005351722240448, 'Y': 0.07888125628232956}, {'X': 0.15451456606388092, 'Y': 0.07883650064468384}]}, 'Id': '223fbbe4-9a0c-4a26-8947-04bb7e535139', 'Page': 1}, 
{'BlockType': 'WORD', 'Confidence': 99.86099243164062, 'Text': 'Is', 'TextType': 'PRINTED', 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 0.05028943344950676, 'Height': 0.010319724678993225, 'Left': 0.1861930638551712, 'Top': 0.06834923475980759}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 0.1862039864063263, 'Y': 0.06834923475980759}, {'X': 0.23648250102996826, 'Y': 0.06843730062246323}, {'X': 0.23647181689739227, 'Y': 0.07866895943880081}, {'X': 0.1861930638551712, 'Y': 0.0785808339715004}]}, 'Id': '1bc8b80b-4e35-4815-9843-ac901852e720', 'Page': 1}], 
'DetectDocumentTextModelVersion': '1.0', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'b6179e12-c603-4a2b-8a4f-171e5c722756', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'b6179e12-c603-4a2b-8a4f-171e5c722756', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '2571', 'date': 'Tue, 18 Oct 2022 13:34:52 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

But when I deploy the calling function on lambda, the OCR only returns:

```
{'DocumentMetadata': 
{'Pages': 1}, 
'JobStatus': 'SUCCEEDED', 
'Blocks': [
{'BlockType': 'PAGE', 'Geometry': {'BoundingBox': {'Width': 1.0, 'Height': 1.0, 'Left': 0.0, 'Top': 0.0}, 'Polygon': [{'X': 3.7998024282615006e-08, 'Y': 0.0}, {'X': 1.0, 'Y': 0.000705239363014698}, {'X': 1.0, 'Y': 1.0}, {'X': 0.0, 'Y': 0.9995841383934021}]}, 'Id': '6a2b1917-731e-49ae-8620-2b61c3e75cf8', 'Page': 1}], 
'DetectDocumentTextModelVersion': '1.0', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'cbe6c3b8-c60f-4990-b771-0620a2d08bd4', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'cbe6c3b8-c60f-4990-b771-0620a2d08bd4', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '388', 'date': 'Tue, 18 Oct 2022 13:09:08 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Here is my ocr code:

```
def InvokeTextDetectJob(s3BucketName, objectName):
    response = None
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.start_document_text_detection(
        DocumentLocation={
            'S3Object':{
                'Bucket': s3BucketName, 
                'Name': objectName}})
    return response['JobId']

def CheckJobComplete(jobId):
    time.sleep(5)
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
    status = response['JobStatus']
    print('Job status: {}'.format(status))
    while(status == 'IN_PROGRESS'):
        time.sleep(5)
        response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
        status = response['JobStatus']
        print('Job status: {}'.format(status))
    return status

def JobResults(jobId):
    pages = []
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
    pages.append(response)
    print('resultset page received: {}'.format(len(pages)))
    nextToken = None
    if 'NextToken' in response:
        nextToken = response['NextToken']
    while(nextToken):
            response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId, NextToken=nextToken)
            pages.append(response)
            nextToken = None
            if 'NextToken' in response:
                nextToken = response['NextToken']
    return pages

def OCR_V2(pdf, bucket_name):
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
    random_name = get_random_string(10) + ".pdf"
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).upload_fileobj(pdf, random_name)
    jobId = InvokeTextDetectJob(bucket_name, random_name)
    if(CheckJobComplete(jobId)):
        response = JobResults(jobId)
        final_response = []

        for resultPage in response:
            if 'Blocks' in resultPage.keys():
                for item in resultPage["Blocks"]:
                    if item["BlockType"] == "LINE":
                        final_response.append(item['Text'])
        return ' '.join(final_response)
```

When fastapi runs locally it works and when the server runs on Lambda, wether I call it from a frontend interface or from the swagger interface, I still only get an incomplete return from the OCR. I've added the full S3 and Textract permissions on the lambda role.

Comment: If you use `print(response)`, does the `Blocks` data appear in the debug file in CloudWatch Logs?

Comment: What is the contents of your `InvokeTextDetectJob()` function?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the second return in my OP is the full output I get from printing the response in the cloudwatch logs. So I have the Blocks data but only for PAGE. When my document has multiple pages, I have multiple PAGE Blocks, but still no LINE or WORD block

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've edited my OP to include the full OCR file.

Comment: It might also be worthwhile logging the version of boto3 being used in Lambda (`print(boto3.__version__)`) in case that is causing the issue.

Comment: 1.24.92, it's the version I've specified in my requirements.txt file for the lambda layer

Comment: Are you sure that they are being run against the _same_ document? The PAGE bounding box is coming through differently.

Comment: Yes I upload exactly the same documents, so something must happen to them when I upload them to the lambda before it even reaches the OCR. It is weird though because the document has 2 pages so and the OCR sees 2 pages so it's not like it would get an empty pdf or something.